# running JavaScript file to excute mongodb queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have for example a list of .find() queries like this:

```
db.tweets.find({},{"user.name":1}).explain()
```

I want to run the queries from a javascript file
then save outputs to a text file

the important thing for me is getting the results from the .explain() in the text file too

is this possible? and how can I achieve this?

Comment: What does `explain()` method return?

Comment: Yes it is possible, here is the manual for this topic: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: the explain() method returns some useful information about the exexution of the query here is a example: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/       @IvanJ

Comment: I have looked at the manual but havent found it useful I was hoping for get a example or easier to understand explaination @user3415653

Comment: Not sure how you can save file with JavaScript. If you are trying to write a file on client machine, You can't do this in any cross-browser way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example script test.js:

```
conn = new Mongo('hostname');
db = conn.getDB('dbName');

var temp =  db.collection.find().explain()

// do what ever you want
printjson(temp)
```

run on command line:

```
mongo hostname test.js
```

output:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9 connecting to: hostname/test 
{
  "cursor": "BasicCursor",
  "isMultiKey": false,
  "n": 4795,
  "nscannedObjects": 4795,
  "nscanned": 4795,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 4795,
  "nscannedAllPlans": 4795,
  "scanAndOrder": false,
  "indexOnly": false,
  "nYields": 0,
  "nChunkSkips": 0,
  "millis": 2,
  "indexBounds": {
  },
  "server": "XXX:XXX"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `explain()` method returns JSON, you can save it into a variable.

```
var temp = db.tweets.find({},{"user.name":1}).explain();
```